# Flutter: Non-nullable instance field 'currentLocation' must be initialised

Tags: flutter

I'm getting an error with the new flutter changes on null safety. Am not sure whether I am supposed to add final/late/! in this code.

I have a code to connect to Google Maps and now I want to be able to store the data collected.

Right now I facing an error at the Application Bloc: `Non-nullable field 'currentLocation' must be initialized.`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hawkepedia/services/geolocator_Services.dart';

import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class ApplicationBloc with ChangeNotifier {
  final geoLocatorService = GeolocatorService();

  //Variables
 Position currentLocation;

  //fire function when the app starts
  ApplicationBloc(){
    setCurrentLocation();
  }

  //gets current location
  setCurrentLocation() async {
    currentLocation = await geoLocatorService.getCurrentLocation();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is state in the error, the field causing the issue is currentLocation.

You can:

- set it as `late` meaning you will initilize it during initState for example.
- set it a nullable, not sure it is possible in this case, `Position? currentLocation`. (But it is for primary types)
- Initialize it with a neutral value that you know is not initialized yet

---

Edit:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hawkepedia/services/geolocator_Services.dart';

import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class ApplicationBloc with ChangeNotifier {
  final geoLocatorService = GeolocatorService();

  //Variables
 late Position currentLocation;

  //fire function when the app starts
  ApplicationBloc(){
    setCurrentLocation();
  }

  //gets current location
  setCurrentLocation() async {
    currentLocation = await geoLocatorService.getCurrentLocation();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Wapazz, I've tried to change my code to the below but it still gets an error. How do I initalise it at the initState?

setCurrentLocation() async {
    late currentLocation = await geoLocatorService.getCurrentLocation();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

Comment: that was a generic answer you dont have initState outside of a Widget

Comment: you have to specify the late keyword at the declaration of the variable, at the top of your class not inside your function

Comment: So it works, if you dont have the error anymore doesnt it ? :) It's just another issue in your code. Maybe create another one with the details of the code where it loads the data, etc.

Comment: Hi @Wapazz, I've tried your method but it still does not work. I have also tried to change my code to "Position? currentLocation'. However, as I have a Futures command in another dart page called "Future<Position> getCurrentLocation() async", my code just keeps loading and the debug console indicates "<asynchronous suspension>"